# Revision Control Table for SOP

Tags: document-classes

I am using my own class which was based on class "Book". Now, I want to create a table for revision records.

I am thinking of something like:

```
\revcont{}{}{}{}{}
\revcont{}{}{}{}{}
```

where each `\revcont` symbolizes a row and each `{}` is a column. Now, I want to add code to `my.cls` to create an output like the attached images.
[image]

I am very poor when it comes to classes. I am making my own class based on other people answers and tutorials.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a little more work beforehand, and end up with a far more flexible system I would use a key-value system here. This has the advantages that:

a) You can easily add more keys later for different tables or the same tables, while excluding or adding whatever columns you want to particular tables
b) You can do various calculations, indexing and other things.

Below is an example. I have not tried to reproduce  your table exactly, or to achieve a nice table layout. You will need to do your own studying to figure out how this will work for you, but it is not at all hard.

The last two columns are slightly more complex examples to show how you can do fancier things. The second last column shows how you could create different variations of the key for going to different places (in this case two separate variants, one for the table and another which you could use elsewhere for example in an index). The last column shows how you could deal with different values at table printing time (in this case the element is a label, and you could leave the column blank if the label is absent, or print a reference and page reference if it is present)

As I said this is just a model, not an answer to your exact exercise.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{ifthen}%this is only optional used here to show how you could do an optional formatting

%cemtab in the below could be changed to anything you like for a particular key set, so can have several sets
\makeatletter
\define@key      [PRE] {cemtab}     {fname}  {\gdef\myfname{#1}}
\define@key      [PRE] {cemtab}     {sname}  {\gdef\mysname{#1}}
\define@key      [PRE] {cemtab}     {city}  {\gdef\mycity{#1}}
\define@key      [PRE] {cemtab}     {plot}  {\gdef\myplot{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{\myplot}{}}{\gdef\myplotbr{}}{\gdef\myplotbr{ (plot #1)}}}%second macro with brackets as cannot have macros in index macro
\define@key      [PRE] {cemtab}     {figref}  {\gdef\myfigref{#1}}

\presetkeys         [PRE] {cemtab} {fname =,
    sname =,
    city =,
    plot =,
    figref =,}{}%

\makeatother

 \newcommand{\personage}[1]{%
\setkeys[PRE]{cemtab}{#1}%
 \mysname & \myfname & \mycity & \myplot & \ifthenelse{\equal{\myfigref}{}}{}{\ref{\myfigref} \pageref{\myfigref}}\\
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\personage{sname=Smith,fname=Reuben,city=York,plot=213,figref=}
\personage{sname=Jones,fname=Peter,city=Norwich,plot=213,figref=}
\personage{sname=Steele,fname=Reuben,city={example, with comma},plot=213,figref=}
%\personage{sname=Steele,fname=Reuben,city=London,plot=213,figref=afiglabel}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, I will look at it and do some more homework and come back again. Thx